# Finding unique elements in a nested cell array of strings

Tags: matlab, cell

Define

```
A = {{'str_a','str_b'},{'str_b','str_c'},{'str_a'},{'str_b','str_c','str_d'}}
```

I want to find the unique elements of the above. That is, I want the output to be

```
{'str_a','str_b','str_c','str_d'}
```

Applying unique results in the following error

```
unique(A)
Error using cell/unique (line 85)
Input A must be a cell array of strings.
```

Comment: You give examples that are all the same length, 5 characters long.  Does the actual data contain the same length strings as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can flatten the nested cell arrays into a single cell array using `{:}` indexing combined with horizontal concatenation, and then use `unique` on that to find the unique strings.

```
unique(cat(2, A{:}))    % Or unique([A{:}])
```

Comment: Ah, thanks, I was experimenting with A{:} and couldn't figure out how to collect the output. It seems like [A{:}] does the same thing. Is this just shorthand for cat(2,A{:})?

Comment: @jonem Yes that is a less-expilcit version of the same thing `[]` performs implicit horizontal concatenation. `horzcat(A{:})` also does the same thing, `cat` performs concatenation on the dimension specified by the first input